# Gradle Plugin not found when using wrapper

Tags: gradle

I have a small gradle build which is using a 3rd party plugin it works great while running gradle commands I then added the wrapper task so I could distribute the code and it could be built with non gradle users. When I went to test the gradlew command I can not even run *gradlew tasks* it fails saying the plugin is missing.

Is there some other configuration that needs to happen?

My wrapper task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '1.0-milestone-2'
  jarFile = 'wrapper/wrapper.jar'
}
```

Full build file: https://github.com/beckje01/Multi-Combobox/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: What is your error message? Is it related to the wrapper, or your third party plugin? Did you run 'gradle wrapper' before trying to issue anything via 'gradlew'?

Comment: Yes I ran wrapper first, the error message is that the plugin is not found.

Comment: Can you post the part of your Gradle script that defines the plugin?

Comment: Yes, this is just not enough info to debug this problem.

Comment: I posted a link to the build file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://tellurianring.com/wiki/gradle/jslib) of this plugin you got to build it from the source code and put it into the directory `lib/plugins` of your Gradle distribution. My guess is that's what you did before you switched to the Gradle wrapper. Whenever you use the Gradle wrapper your locally installed distribution is not used anymore. Gradle downloads the distribution and puts it under `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-2`. One way to get this running would be to put the plugin in there as you did before. However, this won't make it running for somebody else that checks out your code and runs the build. This is the whole point of using the Gradle wrapper.

What I would do in your case is to upload the plugin artifact to a central repository and refer to it in your build script. It doesn't look like it would be available on Maven Central though. You can upload it to your GitHub project and refer to it in your build script like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = 'GitHub'
            addArtifactPattern 'http://cloud.github.com/downloads/[organisation]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'beckje01:jslib:0.5'
        classpath 'com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:r706'
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work I will give it a try, I was just under the impression the point of the wrapper task was to actually bundle all that up for you so I assumed it would grab the installed plugins for you but I guess I was a bit off.